# Is there way to make tar execute a script when switching tape drives?

Tags: tar, tape

My company has a dual Dell LTO-7 drive. I've recently discovered that it's possible to automatically back up to two tapes, sequentially:

```
tar -cv --multi-volume --file=/dev/nst0 --file=/dev/nst1 gigantic10TBfile.bin
```

Excellent. Each tape is 6TB native capacity, we assume the `gigantic10TBfile.bin` doesn't compress, when the tape in `/dev/nst0` is full, tar automatically moves on the the tape in `/dev/nst1`, and I don't have to leave my chair.

Now, in reality, it's not a gigantic file, it's thousands of smaller files. I `tee` the output of tar to a log file to see how things went. In the case of a transfer spanning multiple tapes, I'd like an entry in this log file saying "tape change" or something.

Enter `--new-volume-script` (also known as `--info-script` or `-F`, docs [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Multi_002dVolume-Archives.html#info_002dscript)). Yay. Except it's not executed. Let's make a more manageable example:

```
tar -cvlp --multi-volume --new-volume-script="./new_volume_script.sh" --file=tarball1.tar --file=tarball2.tar --tape-length=4M 10MBrandom.bin
```

Running this example reveals that the `--new-volume-script` is only executed once `tarball1.tar` and `tarball2.tar` have been created, and tar "runs out of" destination files.

So, my question is, is there an option to execute a script between the writing to `tarball1.tar` and `tarball2.tar`?

Comment: Hmm, it says "Only when the first one in the sequence needs to be used again will tar prompt for a tape change (or run the info script)", so yes, it is only executed when '"runs out of" destination files'

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, it is executed only when `tar` runs out of destination files, so in order to run the script each time a volume is created  you have to use only one destination file in your command e.g.

```
tar -cv -M -F './my_script.sh' --file=/dev/nst1 --tape-length=4M 10MBrandom.bin
```

and have the script create the other archives. The script inherits `tar`’s shell environment and additional data is passed to it via  environment variables e.g.:

> TAR_ARCHIVE
> The name of the archive `tar` is processing.
>
> TAR_VOLUME
> Ordinal number of the volume `tar` is about to start.
>
> TAR_FD
> File descriptor which can be used to communicate the new volume name to `tar`.

So, a script like

```
#! /bin/bash

echo Preparing volume $TAR_VOLUME of $TAR_ARCHIVE.
name=${TAR_ARCHIVE%?}
echo ${name}$TAR_VOLUME >&$TAR_FD
```

would run each time another archive is created and produce `/dev/nst2`, `/dev/nst3` etc. Note that `TAR_VOLUME` starts at `1` (that is the initial volume specified in your command via `--file=`). If you want to use `--file=/dev/nst0` and have the archives numbered consecutively you'll have to subtract `1` from  `TAR_VOLUME`  when passing the volume name to `TAR_FD` e.g. change the last line to

```
echo ${name}$((TAR_VOLUME - 1)) >&$TAR_FD
```

If you only have two tape drives that are always named as `/dev/nst0` and `/dev/nst1` and want the script to work when either one or the other is used as initial `--file` argument, you could extract the drive number from the current value of `TAR_ARCHIVE` and use the other drive number when you write the next archive name to `TAR_FD`:

```
#! /bin/bash

echo Preparing volume $TAR_VOLUME of $TAR_ARCHIVE.

drive=${TAR_ARCHIVE: -1}

case "$drive"  in
0)  other=1     ;;
1)  other=0     ;;
*)       exit 1
esac

echo "${TAR_ARCHIVE%?}${other}" >&$TAR_FD
```

This would create two archives, `/dev/nst1` and `/dev/nst0` or vice-versa, the first being the one you specified on the command line via `--file`

---

For the record, here is the quote from the manual ([section 9.6.1](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#Multi_002dVolume-Archives)) including the sample script provided there:

> the most flexible approach is to use a volume script, that writes new
> archive name to the file descriptor `$TAR_FD`. For example, the
> following volume script will create a series of archive files, named
> *‘archive-vol’*, where *archive* is the name of the archive being created
> (as given by `--file` option) and *vol* is the ordinal number of the
> archive being created:

```
#! /bin/bash
# For this script it's advisable to use a shell, such as Bash,
# that supports a TAR_FD value greater than 9.

echo Preparing volume $TAR_VOLUME of $TAR_ARCHIVE.

name=`expr $TAR_ARCHIVE : '\(.*\)-.*'`
case $TAR_SUBCOMMAND in
-c)       ;;
-d|-x|-t) test -r ${name:-$TAR_ARCHIVE}-$TAR_VOLUME || exit 1
          ;;
*)        exit 1
esac

echo ${name:-$TAR_ARCHIVE}-$TAR_VOLUME >&$TAR_FD
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I suppose the only way forward would be to make sure that TAR_FD receives "/dev/nst1" on the second go-around, and possibly, for backups spanning more than two tapes, to alternative between nst0 and nst1.

Comment: `/dev/nst0` etc. are physical LTO-7 tape drives, and I only have two of those. If the volumes were files, you are correct.

Comment: @bolind - ok, I didn't understand that you have only two drives. I've updated my post, HTH